# How to save multi value from checkboxs into database using php

Tags: php, database, checkbox

I am trying to save multiple values into a database.

What I am doing is this; I have a table called location which has id and locationName, I get all the location values from the database and display them in a form so the user can select multiple locations.

```
<input type="checkbox" size="40" name="location[]" value="'.$location[$j]["id"].'" />'
```

Now can any one tell me what will be the best solution to save it into database?

Should I create a field for each location in the table or will one field work?

I also need something which can help me to make a better search that I dont have to write too much code for.

Answer (score 0):

Two simple ways off of the top of my head.

You can make a many to many linking table that will pair the primary key of the user and the primary key of the location.

Another option is to put them all into one field in your user table by using `json_encode()` or `serialize()` to parse the `$_POST['location']` array into a machine readable string form.

Answer (score 0):

The way I did this recently was to simply take the array that you get in `$_POST['location']` and implode it using `implode(',', $_POST['location'])`.

This will give you a string that you can easily store in a single field in the database. Later when you retrieve the data, explode it again to get the array.